# Graphics and sound hang for seconds at a time in games

Tags: windows-10, freeze

This has been happening as long as I can remember after "upgrading" to Windows 10 from Windows 7 last Summer. I didn't have this trouble whatsoever running on the same hardware, but this has started happening with Windows 10.

**Symptoms**

When I'm playing games, the sound and/or video will completely hang for seconds at a time. Sometimes just the video, sometimes just the sound, and sometimes both.

Here's a video of it happening in Hitman 3, but it's also happened in Back4Blood, Rainbow Six, and other games, in the same manner. Here's a link to the same video with sound: https://clipchamp.com/watch/883ZfbwlmOJ

You can see the hanging video, hanging music (while the other audio is still active), and hanging game sounds all in that clip.

Here's another clip with seconds-at-a-time lagging on Starcraft 2 (a 12 year old game) https://clipchamp.com/watch/SSTIMkbzIoS

Other than these times hanging, games run with a high FPS.

This problem also seems to manifest itself in a couple of other ways. For one, when I alt-tab out of a game like this, doing any other task on the PC is basically impossible. I can't even do a Google image search, it just won't happen. It would also take over a minute to open Task Manager.

**Specs**

- MSI Z370 SLI PLUS (MS-7B46)
- Intel Core i5 8400
- Asus GeForce GTX 1070 Ti (GP 104-300 A1) 8GB
- G.Skill 2x 8GB DDR4-2133 (1066 MHz)

**Troubleshooting so far**

- Reinstalled Windows 10
- Uninstalled all NVidia Drivers and reinstalled
- Uninstalled and installed updated sound drivers
- Stress test and no problems or overheating with GPU or CPU, and all fans are running fine
- Ran Windows memory diagnostic tool and found no errors
- Stopped any startup programs that weren't necessary
- *Installed the same game on SSD and HDD to see if it was a disk reading problem

**Help**

I'm not really sure where to go next.

It's not a problem with a specific game

If it's a hardware problem, I can't see any direct symptoms from a particular component, and it seems strange that it coincided with upgrading to Windows 10.

If it's something wrong with Windows 10, it must be endemic since a reinstall didn't fix the problem...

Comment: I'd normally say that it sounds like thermal throttling but it sounds like you've ruled that out. Other than that it also sounds like your system is running fine and I wonder if it could be memory related. Some other program may be using memory (browser or such) and the game is having to halt while memory is paged in or out for the other program. Can you post a copy of your Task Manager -> Performance -> Memory tab while playing a game? The specific number I'd be interested in is the "Committed" memory as well as "In use"

Comment: If it were a hardware fault then I'd expect crashing or a black screen for a few seconds. The kind of "stalling" behaviour you are seeing suggests either throttling by hardware or by bottleneck with something else stealing resource temporarily. It might be worth enabling or disabling "Game mode" in Windows as apparently it may help or hinder depending on your system: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=windows+game+mode

Comment: Specifically it seems "May 2020, Guru 3D wrote about reports of Game Mode leading to stutters and frozen screens with both NVIDIA and AMD graphics hardware." from https://www.howtogeek.com/706859/did-you-know-windows-10-pcs-have-game-mode-on-by-default/

Comment: @Mokubai Wow, thank you so much! It seems like game mode was the problem. I turned it off, and everything is just as snappy as it was on Windows 7. Some game mode!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently on some systems or games the Windows Game Mode, which is meant to improve game performance by lowering the priority of other system tasks, can actually have the opposite effect.

From [H2G: Did You Know? Windows 10 PCs Have “Game Mode” on by Default](https://www.howtogeek.com/706859/did-you-know-windows-10-pcs-have-game-mode-on-by-default/)

> in May 2020, [Guru 3D](https://www.guru3d.com/news-story/windows-10-game-mode-can-impact-fps-negatively-with-stutters-and-freezes.html) wrote about reports of Game Mode leading to stutters and frozen screens with both NVIDIA and AMD graphics hardware.

You can disable Game Mode by typing "game mode" at the start menu, or by opening the control panel and going to **Gaming** -> **Game Mode**, and switching the toggle for **Game Mode** to **Off**

[image]