# PC freeze randomly when playing games

Tags: windows-10, freeze, crash, led

Since last Monday, my friend's computer experience random freezes when he is playing + streaming using OBS. When it happens, he still have the sound, but the image is frozen, the live is going off and he has to do a hard reboot manually.

Moreover, when it happens, he cannot reboot his computer instantly. He has to wait 2 or 3 minutes before being able to restart it.

His configuration :

- MSI Z270-A Pro motherboard
- Processor Intel 6700K
- GPU NVIDIA 1080
- An AIO for cooling
- 2x8Go RAM
- 1 SSD + 2hdd

The AIO seems to work and he has done a 15min benchmark using Heaven Benchmark on extreme profile, but nothing happened... (The GPU reached 72C at the end of the test). He reinstalled Windows completely yesterday but it didn't solve the issue.

We ran a Windows memory test, but when trying to reboot the computer an error code occured on the MB for 2-3 minutes (we were not able to restart the computer for 2-3 minutes). This is the error LED we have had (The "CPU" one) :

[image]

We don't know if it's linked to the initial error. After that the Windows memory test report didn't show us any error.

We cannot reproduce the error on demand since it's really random... At this point we don't know what to do or what can cause the issue...

Any idea ? :(

Comment: Run Control Panel, Security and Maintenance, Maintenance, Reliability Monitor. What software (and hardware) errors are there. Get the Manufacturer's Hardware Diagnostic App and test all hardware.

Comment: is the PSU overheating? I see a lot of dust in that photo

Comment: Could be another problem with Game Mode? https://superuser.com/questions/1702496/graphics-and-sound-hang-for-seconds-at-a-time-in-games/1702629#1702629

Comment: `cannot reboot his computer instantly` ... probably has to wait for the PC to cool down